# Using Timer on a Paint Component

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel

I'm trying to make a visual representation of the traveling salesman problem using a genetic algorithm. I think I got most of it down but I need to slow the repaint() so i can see what's happening each iteration. Any idea how I should implement the actionPerformed() method while retaining the doGA() logic?

```
 class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

  private final static int POINTWIDTH = 8;
  private final static Color POINTCOLOR = Color.RED;
  private final static Color LINECOLOR = Color.GREEN;
  private JLabel label =  new JLabel();
  private City city,city2,city3,city4,city5,city6,city7,city8,city9,city10,city11,city12,city13,city14,city15,city16,city17,city18,city19,city20;
  private Population population;
  private ArrayList tempCity = new ArrayList<City>();
  private ArrayList tempCity2 = new ArrayList<City>();

  int delay = 5000;

  Timer timer = new Timer(delay, this);


  public void start(){
      timer.start();

  }

  public void doGA(){
           city = new City(60, 200);
          TourManager.addCity(city);
          city2 = new City(180, 200);
          TourManager.addCity(city2);
         city3 = new City(80, 180);
          TourManager.addCity(city3);
          city4 = new City(140, 180);
          TourManager.addCity(city4);
           city5 = new City(20, 160);
          TourManager.addCity(city5);
          city6 = new City(100, 160);
          TourManager.addCity(city6);
          city7 = new City(200, 160);
          TourManager.addCity(city7);
          city8 = new City(140, 140);
          TourManager.addCity(city8);
          city9 = new City(40, 120);
          TourManager.addCity(city9);
          city10 = new City(100, 120);
          TourManager.addCity(city10);
           city11 = new City(180, 100);
          TourManager.addCity(city11);
           city12 = new City(60, 80);
          TourManager.addCity(city12);
          city13 = new City(120, 80);
          TourManager.addCity(city13);
          city14 = new City(180, 60);
          TourManager.addCity(city14);
           city15 = new City(20, 40);
          TourManager.addCity(city15);
           city16 = new City(100, 40);
          TourManager.addCity(city16);
           city17 = new City(200, 40);
          TourManager.addCity(city17);
           city18 = new City(20, 20);
          TourManager.addCity(city18);
           city19 = new City(60, 20);
          TourManager.addCity(city19);
          city20 = new City(160, 20);
          TourManager.addCity(city20);
          population = new Population(50, true);

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                    population = GA.evolvePopulation(population);
                    repaint();
                    System.out.println(population.getFittest().getFitness());
                }

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
          g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
          for(int x = 0; x<19;x++){
              g2.setColor(LINECOLOR);
              //g2.drawLine(tempCity.get(x).getX(), tempCity.get(x).getY(), tempCity2.get(x).getX(), tempCity2.get(x).getY());
              g2.drawLine(population.getFittest().getCity(x).getX(), population.getFittest().getCity(x).getY(), population.getFittest().getCity(x+1).getX(), population.getFittest().getCity(x+1).getY());
              g2.setColor(POINTCOLOR);
              g2.fillOval(population.getFittest().getCity(x).getX() - POINTWIDTH/2, population.getFittest().getCity(x).getY() - POINTWIDTH/2, POINTWIDTH, POINTWIDTH);


          }
          g2.setColor(LINECOLOR);
          g2.drawLine(population.getFittest().getCity(19).getX(), population.getFittest().getCity(19).getY(), population.getFittest().getCity(0).getX(), population.getFittest().getCity(0).getY());
          g2.setColor(POINTCOLOR);
          g2.fillOval(population.getFittest().getCity(0).getX() - POINTWIDTH/2, population.getFittest().getCity(0).getY() - POINTWIDTH/2, POINTWIDTH, POINTWIDTH);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        doGA();

    }
```

}

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see the result of every iteration of the for loop in paintComponent()? If so, `x` should be an instance variable, and it should be incremented every time your timer's action is executed (and reset to 0 once it reached 19). The paintComponent method should not loop.

Comment: I want to see the result of doGA's iteration. Right now I set the counter to 100 generations and want to see the updated shapes of paintcomponent every 5 seconds. Now problem right now is i'm not sure where to put doGA, or timer.start().

Comment: Then do what I suggested above, but replace `x` by `i`.

Comment: On each iteration of the actionPerformed method, you need to increment the step and update the state of the program, this would suggest that you need to change your for-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the `Timer` becomes you `for-loop`, so each time it ticks, you need to increment it's iteration and update the state of the model before it's painted.

This means you will HAVE to separate the initialisation and update phases of your code, for example...

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private final static int POINTWIDTH = 8;
    private final static Color POINTCOLOR = Color.RED;
    private final static Color LINECOLOR = Color.GREEN;
    private JLabel label =  new JLabel();
    private City city,city2,city3,city4,city5,city6,city7,city8,city9,city10,city11,city12,city13,city14,city15,city16,city17,city18,city19,city20;
    private Population population;
    private ArrayList tempCity = new ArrayList<City>();
    private ArrayList tempCity2 = new ArrayList<City>();

    int delay = 5000;
    private int iteration = 0;

    Timer timer = new Timer(delay, this);


    public void start(){
        iteration = 0;
        timer.start();
    }

    public void initGA() {
        city = new City(60, 200);
        TourManager.addCity(city);
        city2 = new City(180, 200);
        TourManager.addCity(city2);
        city3 = new City(80, 180);
        TourManager.addCity(city3);
        city4 = new City(140, 180);
        TourManager.addCity(city4);
        city5 = new City(20, 160);
        TourManager.addCity(city5);
        city6 = new City(100, 160);
        TourManager.addCity(city6);
        city7 = new City(200, 160);
        TourManager.addCity(city7);
        city8 = new City(140, 140);
        TourManager.addCity(city8);
        city9 = new City(40, 120);
        TourManager.addCity(city9);
        city10 = new City(100, 120);
        TourManager.addCity(city10);
        city11 = new City(180, 100);
        TourManager.addCity(city11);
        city12 = new City(60, 80);
        TourManager.addCity(city12);
        city13 = new City(120, 80);
        TourManager.addCity(city13);
        city14 = new City(180, 60);
        TourManager.addCity(city14);
        city15 = new City(20, 40);
        TourManager.addCity(city15);
        city16 = new City(100, 40);
        TourManager.addCity(city16);
        city17 = new City(200, 40);
        TourManager.addCity(city17);
        city18 = new City(20, 20);
        TourManager.addCity(city18);
        city19 = new City(60, 20);
        TourManager.addCity(city19);
        city20 = new City(160, 20);
        TourManager.addCity(city20);
        population = new Population(50, true);
    }

    public void doGA(){
        population = GA.evolvePopulation(population);
        repaint();
        System.out.println(population.getFittest().getFitness());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        for(int x = 0; x<19;x++){
            g2.setColor(LINECOLOR);
            //g2.drawLine(tempCity.get(x).getX(), tempCity.get(x).getY(), tempCity2.get(x).getX(), tempCity2.get(x).getY());
            g2.drawLine(population.getFittest().getCity(x).getX(), population.getFittest().getCity(x).getY(), population.getFittest().getCity(x+1).getX(), population.getFittest().getCity(x+1).getY());
            g2.setColor(POINTCOLOR);
            g2.fillOval(population.getFittest().getCity(x).getX() - POINTWIDTH/2, population.getFittest().getCity(x).getY() - POINTWIDTH/2, POINTWIDTH, POINTWIDTH);

        }
        g2.setColor(LINECOLOR);
        g2.drawLine(population.getFittest().getCity(19).getX(), population.getFittest().getCity(19).getY(), population.getFittest().getCity(0).getX(), population.getFittest().getCity(0).getY());
        g2.setColor(POINTCOLOR);
        g2.fillOval(population.getFittest().getCity(0).getX() - POINTWIDTH/2, population.getFittest().getCity(0).getY() - POINTWIDTH/2, POINTWIDTH, POINTWIDTH);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        iteration++;
        if (iteration < 100) {
            doGA();
        } else {
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
}
```

The short answer would be, no, you can't keep your `doGA` method as it is, it must be changed, there simply is no other way to achieve it, but the longer answer is, it's not that hard if you simply think of the `Timer` as a fancy type of loop...

Comment: Holy moly thank you so much!!!! I sort of though Timer would sort of be a pseudo loop, just never knew how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

IF your objective is to call :

```
population = GA.evolvePopulation(population);
repaint();
System.out.println(population.getFittest().getFitness());
```

every seconds, as example, you could use a thread:

```
int i = 0;

Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
      if i != 100
      {
        Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        System.out.println("Thread Running iteration:" + i );
        i++;
        population = GA.evolvePopulation(population);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
          public void run() 
          {
              // Here, we can safely update the GUI
              // because we'll be called from the
              // event dispatch thread
              repaint();
          }
        });


        System.out.println(population.getFittest().getFitness());


      }
      else
      {
        Thread.currentthread.interrupt()
      }
    }
}

thread.start();
```

You could also use a [timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), as someone mentionned in the comments:

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: this isn't answer to OPs question but returns back to the dinosaures adges Java4, Swing timer is better choice for simple and standard painting

Comment: You are welcome to edit my answer or submit your own if you feel I am answering wrongly :)

I am a novice, I dont claim this is the best answer , Just tought it might work

Comment: Note, that this could potentially violate the single thread rules of Swing and/or result in thread race conditions between the thread and the paint process resulting in unwanted painting artefacts