# How to prevent latency while using too much repaint

Tags: java, paint, repaint

I am trying to make a little game, a plane is up and when i click the down arrow it drops a bomb. If bomb hit the target it changes its place etc...

```
public void paint(Graphics p) {
    p.setColor(c);
    p.drawLine(0, 650, 1000, 650);

    p.fillRect(x3, y3, 150, 50);
    p.fillOval(x2, y2, 30, 30);
    p.drawImage(image, x, y, null);

    if (x < 1000) {
        x = x + 10;
    }

    if (x > 750) {
        x = 0;
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(40);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }

    if (bo==true) {
        x2 = x2 + z;
        y2 = y2 + 8;
    }

    if (y2 > 450 && z != 0) {
        z--;
    }

    if (y2 > 620) {
        x2 =- 100;
        y2 =- 100;
    }

    if (y2 > 610 && x2 < x3 + 150 && x2 > x3) {
        x3 = x3 + 100;
    }

    repaint(1);
}
```

But the problem is at first everything is normal after 1 or 2 seconds fps is like 10, sometimes i cant see the objects, i saw another topic about using timer but i dont want to solve it with timer and even i dont know if i could. I wonder if its about my computer or ide.

Comment: I intended it actually. Since bomb must disappear after going down, and i dont know any other way to make it disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do not `Override` `paint()` method. `Override` `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method (and do not forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Secondly, using `Thread.sleep()` method in EDT (hopefully, you start your application, using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater`) is bad idea, since all events will stop taking place (with few words, the whole GUI will freeze).

You should [use a swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Finally, do not call `repaint()` inside `paintComponent`, because `repaint()` will call `paintComponent` again, and it will be an endless loop. You should repaint the component in Timer`s action listener.

Comment: Actually thats what i want, i dont want it to end. And where should i call super.paintComponent i dont know much about super thing. And why Thread.sleep() does so, i mean freezes GUI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032421/using-timer-on-a-paint-component

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689898/thread-sleep-is-freezing